# Have there been any updates to the HTML drag and drop functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

A few months ago I implemented something on my site which uses drag and drop to allow users to drag buttons on top of a bracelet. Here is a JSFiddle which worked about a month or two ago: http://jsfiddle.net/6xRXj/3/

Within the last month or two, something changed, as the code on my site, nor the code on this JSFiddle works as it used to. The buttons no longer stay in the boxes when dragged.

Does anyone know why this may be, or have any information on any HTML or JS updates which may have affected this? Couldn't find anything on Google.

Thanks in advance.

Code from the JSFiddle: HTML

```
<div id="bracelet">
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="div2" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg" ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div3" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div4" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div5" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag4" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div6" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag5" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div7" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag6" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div8" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag7" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div9" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag8" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div10" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag9" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div11" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag10" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div12" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag11" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div13" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag12" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    var el = ev.target;
    var parent = el.getAttribute("data-parent");

    if(!parent){
        el.setAttribute("data-parent", el.parentNode.id);
    }

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", el.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function dragEnd(ev){
    if(ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect == "none"){
         var parent = document.getElementById(ev.target.getAttribute("data-parent"));

        parent.appendChild(ev.target);
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 50px
}
.drop {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#bracelet {
    width:420px;
    height:75px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: One code tip, IDs **must** be unique. You're duplicating `id="div1"`.